# Segmented Input field using autocmplete and autofocus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I have the following setup

```js
          {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((i) => (
            <Form.Control
              key={"code-cell-" + i}
              className="mx-2 p-0 text-center shadow-none verification-code-cell"
              style={{ fontSize: "1.4em", width: "3em" }}
              inputMode="numeric"
              autoComplete="on"
              size="lg"
              maxLength="1"
              autoFocus={i === 1}
            />
          ))}
```

That renders the following sequence of input boxes

[image]

Currently on desktop and mobile, when I copy the code from the email, tap on the first input and paste the code, all fields are filled with the correct numbers, it works great.

But on mobile when the code is suggested at the top of the keyboard, and I use that autofill suggestion, only the first input is filled, the others remain empty.

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm missing or need to change to make it work?

Comment: Can you try adding the `name` attribute to `<Form.Control />` once and check?

Comment: Thank you, but that change made no difference

Comment: Is there any way to replicate this to experiment around it like on **[code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)**?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you're using **[`React-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/)** library(probably bootstrap-5) to achieve your goals. Considering that, you can try `onPaste` event on the first input field and distribute the pasted characters to the other input fields. Something like below:

```js
// handlePaste function
const handlePaste = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pastedData = e.clipboardData.getData("text");
    const digits = pastedData.split("").slice(0, 6);
    digits.forEach((digit, index) => {
      if (inputRefs.current[index]) {
        inputRefs.current[index].value = digit;
        if (index < 5) {
          inputRefs.current[index + 1].focus();
        }
      }
    });
  };
// Some of your code...

{[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((i) => (
          <Form.Control
            key={"code-cell-" + i}
            name={"code-cell-" + i}
            className="mx-2 p-0 text-center shadow-none verification-code-cell"
            style={{ fontSize: "1.4em", width: "3em" }}
            inputMode="numeric"
            autoComplete="on"
            size="lg"
            maxLength="1"
            autoFocus={i === 1}
            ref={(el) => (inputRefs.current[i - 1] = el)}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(i - 1, e)}
            onPaste={i === 1 ? handlePaste : null}
          />
        ))}
```

You can find the implementation of above code sample in **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-rubin-dzc88f?file=/src/App.js:318-708&resolutionWidth=488&resolutionHeight=675)**